# Computing intersection multiplicity using the completion

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface over complex numbers. Let $C$ and $D$ be two curves and $p\in C\cap D$ be a smooth point of both curves. I want to calculate the intersection multiplicity $(C\cdot D)_p$ which is defined to be
$$\text{dim}\frac{O_{X,p}}{(f,g)}$$
where $f,g$ are the defining equations of $C$ and $D$ in the stalk. Is this the same as
$$\text{dim}\frac{\widehat{O_{X,p}}}{(f',g')}$$
where $f',g'$ are the local equations of $C$ and $D$ in the completion of the stalk?

Comment: When you talk about the dimension, you refer to the $C$-vector space dimension. The ring in question has Krull dimension 0, so it is already complete.

Comment: I am only taking the completion of thr stalk, not the quotient.

Comment: Those two processes commute.